# React State is empty when function is called via event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a function called `handleSearchClick()` that deletes All MapBox markers and adds the new ones. When this is used via a button click this works as expected. However when i use this within the Mapbox Geocoder on method found [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/main/API.md#on) it fails as the `mapMarkers` array is empty.

**handleSearchClick Function**

```
const [mapMarkers, setMarkers] = useState(stateMakrers);

const handleSearchClick = () => {
        const sw = map.current.getBounds().getSouthWest();
        const ne = map.current.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        const nw = map.current.getBounds().getNorthWest();
        const se = map.current.getBounds().getSouthEast();

        const bounds = [{ longitude: sw.lng, latitude: sw.lat }, { longitude: nw.lng, latitude: nw.lat }, { longitude: ne.lng, latitude: ne.lat }, { longitude: se.lng, latitude: se.lat }, { longitude: sw.lng, latitude: sw.lat }];
        
        console.log(mapMarkers);

        mapMarkers.forEach((marker) => marker.remove())
        setMarkers([]);
        setList([]);
        getMapCourses(bounds).then((data) => {
            data.forEach((marker) => {
                setList(arr => [...arr, renderListItem(marker)]);
                const m = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                    .setLngLat([marker.longitude, marker.latitude])
                    .setPopup(
                        new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
                            .setHTML(`<p>${marker.name}</p>`)
                    )
                    .addTo(map.current);
                    setMarkers(ms => [...ms, m]);
            });
         });
    };
```

I have `setMarkers(ms => [...ms, m]);` that sets all the markers ready to delete all whenever the function is ran. i loop thorugh each marker here `mapMarkers.forEach((marker) => marker.remove())`

i have a button that runs this perfectly

```
<CustomButton type="button" className="search-here-button" onClick={handleSearchClick} >Search This Area</CustomButton>
```

However when this method runs the state `mapMarkers` returns an empty array, which causes markers to be duplicated on the map. I have added a `useEffect` to console line when mapMarkers has changed and returns an array with data. Its just when the `geocoder.on('result', (results) =>` method is triggered again the array is empty.

I'm still learning the ropes with React and have looked into possibly its caused by not re-rendering, but documentation says `setMarkers` should trigger a re-render.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            mapboxgl,
            flyTo:true
        });
        geocoder.on('result', (results) => {

            map.current.jumpTo({
                center: results.result.center,
                zoom: 10
            })
            handleSearchClick();
            console.log(mapMarkers);
        })
        geocoderInput.current.appendChild(geocoder.onAdd(map.current));
    }, [])
```

**Update 1**

i have tried pushing to array within the function and output results to console.
`mms` prints out markers successfully
`mapMarkers` prints out empty array

do i need to trigger a re-render as its within the  `geocoder.on('result')` method?

```
const handleSearchClick = async () => {
        const sw = map.current.getBounds().getSouthWest();
        const ne = map.current.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        const nw = map.current.getBounds().getNorthWest();
        const se = map.current.getBounds().getSouthEast();

        const bounds = [{ longitude: sw.lng, latitude: sw.lat }, { longitude: nw.lng, latitude: nw.lat }, { longitude: ne.lng, latitude: ne.lat }, { longitude: se.lng, latitude: se.lat }, { longitude: sw.lng, latitude: sw.lat }];
        console.log("Handle Search Click Start");
        console.log(mapMarkers);

        // mapMarkers.forEach((marker) => marker.remove())
        setMarkers([]);
        setList([]);
        const mms = [];
        getMapCourses(bounds).then((data) => {
            data.forEach((marker) => {
                setList(arr => [...arr, renderListItem(marker)]);
                const m = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                    .setLngLat([marker.longitude, marker.latitude])
                    .setPopup(
                        new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
                            .setHTML(`<p>${marker.name}</p>`)
                    )
                mms.push(m);
            });
        });
        setMarkers(mms);
        console.log("Markers Set local")
        console.log(mms)
        console.log("Markers Set state ")
        console.log(mapMarkers)

    };
```

**WORKS BUT DOES NOT FEEL GOOD PRACTISE**

I create two arrays one using state and the other just a const. i add to both and delete from both. because if i use the `mms` the button then starts returning empty state array. Is this good practise?

```
const [mapMarkers, setMarkers] = useState(stateMakrers);
const mms = [];
 const handleSearchClick = () => {
        const sw = map.current.getBounds().getSouthWest();
        const ne = map.current.getBounds().getNorthEast();
        const nw = map.current.getBounds().getNorthWest();
        const se = map.current.getBounds().getSouthEast();

        const bounds = [{ longitude: sw.lng, latitude: sw.lat }, { longitude: nw.lng, latitude: nw.lat }, { longitude: ne.lng, latitude: ne.lat }, { longitude: se.lng, latitude: se.lat }, { longitude: sw.lng, latitude: sw.lat }];
        console.log("Handle Search Click Start");
        console.log(mapMarkers);

        mms.forEach((marker) => marker.remove())
        mapMarkers.forEach((marker) => marker.remove())
        setMarkers([]);
        setList([]);
        while (mms.length > 0) {
            mms.pop();
        }
        getMapCourses(bounds).then((data) => {
            data.forEach((marker) => {
                setList(arr => [...arr, renderListItem(marker)]);
                const m = new mapboxgl.Marker()
                    .setLngLat([marker.longitude, marker.latitude])
                    .setPopup(
                        new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
                            .setHTML(`<p>${marker.name}</p>`)
                    ).addTo(map.current)
                mms.push(m);
            });
        });
        setMarkers(mms);
    };
```

Comment: there are 2 events : results { results } Fired when the geocoder returns a response, result { result } Fired when input is set. I guess it should be results , not result

Comment: @phongt sorry i dont understand, the geocoder result centers the map fine. its the handleSearchClIck() thats the issue

Comment: @phongt i need result as this will get the chosen location data, that i use to center. but this isnt where the issue is, its to do with react states

Comment: ohh,. have you console data in   getMapCourses(bounds).then((data) . I guest jumpTo take the time to map update. In that time, bounds just contain small area so data is just empty

Comment: this is fine, its `markers` is an empty array even though the `setMapMarkers()` is used. just seems to be empty within the geocoder event